# "No overload for method 'WndProc' takes 0 arguments"

Tags: c#

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
    {
        if (message.Msg == WM_SETTINGCHANGE)
        {
            if (message.WParam.ToInt32() == SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER)
            {
                // Handle that wallpaper has been changed.
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref message);
    }

    private void check_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WndProc();
    }
```

I know that I'm missing something that goes in the () after WndProc, but I'm not sure *what*... Can someone help?

Comment: It would be a windows message, why are you trying to call the WndProc Method directly?

Comment: @MarkHall I don't care how it happens, I just want the code inside to execute whenever the timer ticks. I got this code from a website (I'm relatively new to C#) and I just tried to call it from the timer.

Comment: Also what do you mean by "It would be a windows message"? How do I do the windows message?

Comment: The WndProc method is away to monitor windows messages being sent to your application. You usually do not call it directly. What are you trying to accomplish, set the Desktop Wallpaper?

Comment: @MarkHall I'm trying to trigger something when I set the wallpaper, yeah.

Comment: How are you setting the wallpaper?

Comment: @MarkHall Using the built-in windows desktop changer. I'm trying to track when a user changes the wallpaper that way.

Comment: @ChaseTheSun I did, and that didn't work... For the record, in the Form1.Designer.cs code, the timer has this:                 this.check.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.check_Tick);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I put a breakpoint in the Windows Message Handler I noticed when the background changes it is receiving a Wparam of 42 not 20, it probably is a combination of Bits so you can try something like this.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_SETTINGCHANGE)
    {
        if ((m.WParam.ToInt32() & (int)SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER) == SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER)
        {
            // Handle that wallpaper has been changed.
        }
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);

}
```

If your are wanting to poll for changes with a timer you can create a Message then call the WndProc Method like this.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Message m = new Message();
    m.Msg = (int)WM_SETTINGCHANGE;
    m.WParam = (IntPtr)SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER;
    WndProc(ref m);

}
```

Comment: When I do that it keeps triggering every time the timer ticks, even if I haven't changed the desktop wallpaper.

Comment: if you use the first method it should just be triggered when the Background changes. The timer will trigger it everytime it ticks, that is why you should let the WndProc respond to the system message. I saw there was some discussion about it not being triggered and a timer suggested. but it was responding correctly on my computer(Win7) everytime I changed the background.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a timer to check for changes, that's the job of WndProc:

```
    private static readonly UInt32 SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x14;
    private static readonly UInt32 WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x1A;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
    {
        if (message.Msg == WM_SETTINGCHANGE)
        {
            if (message.WParam.ToInt32() == SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER)
            {
                // Handle that wallpaper has been changed.]
                 Console.Beep();
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref message);
    }
```

Comment: How often does this check to see if it's changed? I changed it and it still hasn't realized. I'm on Win8 if it matters. Also does it run automatically? Or is there something I need to do to run it?

Comment: it's constantly monitoring for messages, so almost instant

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I just put it in randomly in the program, with nothing triggering it etc and it didn't work.